# Find the distance from the initial location

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, relative-motion

> Sing Huat drives a car with initial speed 30 km/h and acceleration 2 km/h2 toward Tee, whose displacement is 200 m away from him. At the same time, Tee drives another car toward Sing Huat with initial speed 50 km.h and acceleration 3 km/h2. Find the distance from the initial location of Sing Huat, where these two cars will meet.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlyV0.jpg

I wonder is Tee drives two cars at the same time? If so,

> Find the distance from the initial location of Sing Huat, where these two cars will meet.

which two cars the question wants to compare with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the formula:

DelatX = Speed*Time + 0.5*Acceleration*Time²

Calculate the equation for both Tee and Huat, plot this in a graph X(Time), the intersection point of the to parabolas should give you where they meet.

Comment: There is another way to solve it without using graph.
equal the S1 and S2 to find t. Then sub t into S1. S1 = Huat, S2 = Tee